# Exchange 2007 and Exchange Web Services

Tags: exchange

Not a 100% sure this belongs here but here goes nothing.  What is the relationship between EWS versions and Exchange.  I want to use EWS 1.2 which says Exchange 2007 SP2 or up.  What I am asking, I guess, is the EWS version tied to the Exchange version or can I get Exchange 2007, no SP's, work with EWS 1.1 or 1.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the .NET interface for the API (I assume you are, that's by far the easiest way to interface with Windows development), when you're initiating your connection, you must specify which version of Exchange you are connecting to.

```cs
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
```

Because the scripts are backwards compatible, I strongly suggest always using the latest version of the script.

However, I do believe that the minimum version for *any* EWS integration via the .NET API is 2007 SP1.

Comment: Awsome, thank you very much.  PS, can I take this as verification that this is the appropriate location for EWS questions or does it just depend?

Comment: It depends. If its programming 99% belong on stack overflow, but this crossed the line between programming and infrastructure. There are a lot of ews experts on stack overflow so it would have done well there too.